# C# Correct pattern for Paralle.For async await method

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I would like some advise on this method.  Is this a good pattern to go with or will something else perform better?

```
    public async Task<PortfolioLoans> GetSampleOfPortfolioLoanNumbers(int count = 1)
    {
        var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(this.DataMineConnectionString);
        var pfLoans = new PortfolioLoans();

        var ts = new ThreadSafeList<PortfolioLoan>();

        try
        {
          await Task.Run(() => {
              Parallel.For(0, count, async i =>
              {
               var loans = await sqlConn.QueryAsync("dbo.spGetSampleApplicationIDs", Parameters.Empty, Query.Returns<PortfolioLoan>());
               ts.AddRange(loans);
              });

              pfLoans.Loans.AddRange(ts.Clone());
          });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return pfLoans;
    }
```

Comment: is `pfLoans.Loans` a list? if so thats not thread safe

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I'm using [Insight Database](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database) micro orm

Comment: @DanielA.White - Thanks for pointing that out.  I will fix that.

Comment: Only thing I would question is using a Task and Parallel.For...Are you on a UI thread?

Comment: @Mike_G - No UI

Answer (score 1):

The `Parallel` class was relaesed before before async/await. It does ***NOT*** support using `async` in as the method boday. When you use `async` it creates an annonamous `async void` function and because of that it can't tell when the work is complete and it finishes before the tasks you started are done. A more modern set of classes that work with async/await is [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx).

Secondly `sqlConn` is not thread safe, ***you can not use it from multiple threads at the same time.*** You must make a new connection object for each thread.

Lastly I will put money on that `pfLoans.Loans` is a `List<T>` or something similar and is not thread safe. You can not call functions from multiple threads that are not designed to handle calls from multiple threads. You must lock on calls to `AddRange` or change out the class with one that is thread safe.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have experienced the exact scenerio you mention with `Paralle.For` and `async`.  Now I know why it was doing what it was doing.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To clean it up a bit and add thread safety:

```
   public async Task<PortfolioLoans> GetSampleOfPortfolioLoanNumbers(int count = 1)
   {

        var pfLoans;

        try
        {
           pfLoans = await Task.Run(async () => {
              var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(this.DataMineConnectionString);
              var pls = new Portfolioloans();
              for(var i=0; i<count; i++)
              {
                  var loans = await sqlConn.QueryAsync("dbo.spGetSampleApplicationIDs", Parameters.Empty, Query.Returns<PortfolioLoan>());
                  pls.Loans.AddRange(loans);
              }
             return pls;
      });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    return pfLoans;
}
```

Unless those queries are taking too long, i don't know if i would put them in a Parallel.For

edit: i missed the Async on `sqlConn.QueryAsync`, with that if are worried about blocking, then you don't even need a Task since the `QueryAsync` is already async.

```
  public async Task<PortfolioLoans> GetSampleOfPortfolioLoanNumbers(int count = 1)
  {
    var pfLoans = new PortfolioLoan();

    try
    {
          var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(this.DataMineConnectionString);
          var pls = new Portfolioloans();
          for(var i=0; i<count; i++)
          {
              var loans = await sqlConn.QueryAsync("dbo.spGetSampleApplicationIDs", Parameters.Empty, Query.Returns<PortfolioLoan>());
              pfLoans.Loans.AddRange(loans);
          }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }

   return pfLoans;
}
```

Comment: Ran your code through visual studio, you forgot a async before the `()` in `Task.Run(() => {`, fixed it for you.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yeah, thanks, I completely glossed over the async query

Comment: So should I use the `await Task.Run(async () =>` or not?  A lil confused here.  I really appreciate all the feedback.

Comment: @chdev77 you don't need it. You are already using async/await you don't need the extra Task.Run.

Comment: I wouldn't.  Also, remember, just because you use Parallel.For, doesn't guarantee its going to be run in parallel.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - Seems like it is redundant but I got the code from another area someone else did in our project and wanted to follow the same pattern.  Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Mike_G - Correct, I'm familiar with that case.  I appreciate the help.